# Math Parrallelogram Level Generation

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, polygon

I am currently developing a mobile runner. Therefore i need platforms allow the transition from one height to another (2D).

[image: img]

Given: Triangle AFB has a rectangle alpha, Triangle CDE has a rectangle at delta, Line BC = EF, Line ED = AB and the height of the Parralelogram is ED(=AB)

 Looking for: AF = CD (any of both)

I can't find a solution.

Tip: I have a formula for a case where when you can give me a parralel line to the long sides of the parrallelogram I will be able to work out the rest. Couldn't find a parrall line though.

Comment: A parallelogram is a quadrilateral. Since your shape is a hexagon, it cannot be a parallelogram. Anyway, what exactly is your input? The coordinates of the two sharp tips? Do you know the length of the vertical/horizontal line segments? If not, what else do you know? If there is nothing else, then the problem is underspecified.

Comment: Your description is not clear. From your diagram it appears that the long parallel sides are at 45 degree angles to the axes, and the four end segments are congruent. Is that the case? And are you given the midpoints of the two diagonal sides? If so, and if the answer to my first question is yes, then those two points must also be at a 45 degree angle to the axes. And the other comment is correct: you need more information to determine one such figure.

Comment: The input are the two positions in the middle of the ending sides(which is one side of the triangle). Given is also the width of the parrallogram and triangle at the start and end. The whole figure is build up of two triangles(at the bottom left and at the top right) and the parrallelogramm connecting both with the same height.

Comment: The angles do not matter. The resuilting function hast to work for any angle, it is a coincendence, for being 45°

Comment: What are you given and what are you looking for? What do the areas have to do with the length `CD`? Please edit your question to make it clearer what your function is trying to do.

PS. Show the formula you already have and why it doesn't work for the general case.

Comment: "The input are the two positions in the middle of the ending sides": Does that mean that the coordinate pairs of the midpoints (xt,yt)=(C+D)/2 and (xb,yb)=(A+F)/2 of CD and AF are given as input? Alongside with the side lengths a=d and c=f? If so, please update the question in that way so that a definitive answer can be formulated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a re-interpretation as a "planar mechanism" that is possibly still not right in the input description.

Input: the solid fixed triangle at the bottom with short perpendicular sides length `a` and `c`. The top triangle is the same, rotated by 180°, but not fixed. The triangles are connected by bars of length `b` that are rotationally flexible and fixed by giving the angle `phi`.

- bottom triangle:  `A=(0,0), F=(c,0), B=(0,a)`
- lower bar: `F=(c,0), E=(c,0)+b*(cos(phi), sin(phi))`
- upper bar: `B=(0,a), C=(0,a)+b*(cos(phi), sin(phi))`
- upper triangle: `E=(c,0)+b*(cos(phi), sin(phi))`, `D=(c,a)+b*(cos(phi), sin(phi))`, `C=(0,a)+b*(cos(phi), sin(phi))`

---

If not the angle is given, but the total height at the segment `CD`,

```
h=a+b*sin(phi),
```

then the horizontal component can be calculated via trigonometric identity

```
b*cos(phi) = sqrt( b^2 - (h-a)^2 )
```

Set `bsin=b*sin(phi)=h-a`, `bcos=sqrt(b*b-bsin*bsin)` then

```
C=(  bcos, a+bsin)
D=(c+bcos, a+bsin)
E=(c+bcos,   bsin)
```

Comment: a is not given for the calculation so where do you get it from?

Comment: @Paulomato : The question is: What is given for the construction. Without input no (interesting) output.

Comment: look at the reply to the comments above

Comment: @Paulomato : Ok, replace solid rectangle by solid triangles only.

Comment: I don't get what u mean. Sry

Comment: I rewrote the question if that helps

Comment: And how do you calculate phi? or where is phi located?

Comment: Since this is propably based on the theory that the sides of the parralelogram are parralel to the diagonal from A to D, but thats not the case

Comment: No, of course not. See what happens when `phi=0`, i.e., the bars are horizontal. How do you fix one of the edges of the upper triangle? Your description is not very clear on that.

Comment: CD and AF are parrallel and AB also to ED

Comment: Alternative without `phi` as explicit value.

Comment: the length b is also not given D: